# Where do I find Outlook Calendar permission in Outlook 2019?

Tags: outlook

In the previous Outlook versions, I could set permissions like this:

[image]

But where can I find this "Outlook calendar permission" dialog in Outlook 2019?

Regading to this link https://support.office.com/en-us/article/share-an-outlook-calendar-with-other-people-353ed2c1-3ec5-449d-8c73-6931a0adab88 I should be able to find a "Calendar permission" button on the "Home" tab - but this is missing in 2019.

UPDATE:

Posted in wrong forum - sorry ... moved to here: https://superuser.com/questions/1362128/where-do-i-find-outlook-calendar-permission-in-outlook-2019

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: You're quite right - sorry ... I posted in the wrong forum.

Comment: Posted in wrong forum - sorry ... moved to here: https://superuser.com/questions/1362128/where-do-i-find-outlook-calendar-permission-in-outlook-2019

Answer (score 0):

You can get to that dialog from the folder context menu (right on the folder in the folder tree view pane, select "Properties...")

Comment: No, I only see this dialog now ... https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/1d2eec56-4375-450c-b425-d73fade96deb.png ... i will close my question, since it is in the wrong forum.